# Syntactic sugar for Safe Navigation operator(&.)

Tags: ruby, syntactic-sugar, ruby-2.3

```
str = "Hello World!"
str.[] /Hello/    # => "Hello"
str[/Hello/]      # => "Hello", syntactic suger version

str = nil
str&.[] /Hello/   # => nil
str&.[/Hello/]    # => SyntaxError: unexpected '[', expecting '('
str[/Hello/]      # => NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

How can the Safe Navigation operator(`&.`) be used on syntactic sugar for `[]`method?

Comment: `str&.[](/Hello/)` this should be the correct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can the Safe Navigation operator(`&.`) be used on syntactic sugar for `[]`method?

It can't. Matz doesn't want it to.

This feature was requested and rejected twice already:

- [Bug #11618: *Safe call syntax with aref or aset is*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11618)
- [Feature #11813: *Extend safe navigation operator for `[]` and `[]=` with syntax sugar*](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11813)

[Matz says](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11618#note-1):

> I am not going to add safe navigation for aref and aset.
>   Maybe you can use `a.?[](x)` (method call of an operator).

Answer (score 3):

Answer is short - you can't. Becase "method name is syntactically required" from Ruby 2.3 NEWS